# Drawing a symbol resembling half opening/closing bracket

Tags: equations

I want to draw a symbol as below

[image]

I don't seem to find a suitable way to do so.

The best I can think of is to use `\overbrace` and `\underbrace`.

Comment: you mean the lines, right?

Comment: @Gunter yes the lines connecting `b` and `2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do this with tikz. For example, with a tikz matrix:

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(M)[matrix of math nodes]
  {%
        &         &        &     &     &           & 2^m     &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     &           & 2^{m-1} &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         & \ddots &     &     &           & \vdots  &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     &           & 4       &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     &           & 2       &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     &           & 1       &        &        &        &          &        \\
    b_m & b_{m-1} & \cdots & b_2 & b_1 & b_0       & b_{-1}  & b_{-2} & b_{-3} & \cdots & b_{-n+1} & b_{-n} \\
        &         &        &     &     & 1/2       &         &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     & 1/4       &         &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     & 1/8       &         &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     & \vdots    &         &        &        & \ddots &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     & 1/2^{n-1} &         &        &        &        &          &        \\
        &         &        &     &     & 1/2^n     &         &        &        &        &          &        \\
  };
  \node at ($(M-7-6)!0.5!(M-7-7)$) {$\cdot$};
  \foreach\i in {1,2,4,5,6}
  {%
    \draw[thick] (M-7-\i.north) |- (M-\i-7.west);
  }
  \foreach\i in {7,8,9,11,12}
  {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
    \draw[thick] (M-7-\i.south) |- (M-\j-6.east);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**Edit:** As the OP suggested, I changed the `matrix of nodes` for a `matrix of math nodes` which produces less code.

Comment: I was thinking of a tikz solution as well. But mine would have been much more complicated. One question though: Why did you place the \cdot not in the matrix as well?

Comment: @Gunter, it is clearly an option. I did it this way thinking in a possible situation in which you need to put the $b_0$, $b_1$, etc. equidistant. In this case you only need to put `[row sep=x cm]` in the matrix specification, and the `\cdot` will not add more horizontal space.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Having read a bit about matrices in tikz, I would suggest to use the `matrix of math nodes` option to save some more typing :-)

Comment: @Gunter, yep you are absolutely right. I copy-pasted for another matrix without thinking. It is edited now.